# What it is called which is opposite of shadow?

Tags: android, android-drawable, dropshadow

Today I found a nice UI which impressed me a lot. I don't  know what that upper white pops up that I have marked in the picture below. Can anyone tell me what it is called and how we can create in drawable? Any Documentation link would be much more appreciated.Please please no negative votes because I am a newbie and I want to learn. Sorry about my poor english. [image]

Comment: If in a broad sense we were to define shadow as `“diffused light”`, the opposite would then be `“reflected light”` or `simply reflection`.

Comment: @Ironman can u please provide me a documentation link?

Comment: I can not find it doc. But being see the Image we have to give `light shadow` to that part to display what you asking for.

Comment: @Ironman I think you didn't get what I mean. I mean is there's a button in a picture, If you observe it closely you'd find shadow at bottom part and In up part there's something white what is that called?

Comment: @Ironman oh.. I got it. You mean to say that. It is a shadow with white color right? Yeah.. that's the one. okay thank you for your quick response..

Comment: the bottom shadow have `dark color` and upper shadow is `light color`.